# Placing of background image for Tab bar

Tags: ios, image, background, tabbar

I have placed background image on tab bar but the problem is that the second item should have a raised curve of the background. It is looking good in 6s and 6s Plus but not in 5s and 4s.
[The background image looks proper in 6s][1]
[The background image does not look proper in 5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftvb5.png).
How to set background image according to my need in 5s. I have used the following image.
[Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4Sa.png)

Comment: Is this view is of storyboard?

Comment: It is screenshot of simulator

Comment: If the total black bar is image then fix the size. Keep 3 size of that image in image asset 1x, 2x, 3x

Answer (score 0):

Just for iPhone5s and 4s as you say in your side iPhone 6 and 6 Plus looking good.

[image]

This is tabbarBg.png . size 320 * 59. Resized your image for iPhone 4s and 5s.

Place the following code in your AppDelagate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 320) {

        [[UITabBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbarBg.png"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which size you are using for iPhone5? if possible give the background image that i can try mayself.

Comment: i have added the background image in my question

Comment: Please see the edit. I found no other solution then this.